# What does the first three lines in Ride4dApps mean?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

I start writhing my first dApp on RIDE language and I noticed that in smart account these 3 lines of code

```
{-# STDLIB_VERSION 2 #-}
{-# CONTENT_TYPE EXPRESSION #-}
{-# SCRIPT_TYPE ACCOUNT #-}
```

are different in ride4dapps code example in the IDE

```
{-# STDLIB_VERSION 3 #-}
{-# CONTENT_TYPE DAPP #-}
{-# SCRIPT_TYPE ACCOUNT #-}
```

what are these 3 lines for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line `{-# STDLIB_VERSION 2 #-}` stands for the standard library version(the latest version is STDLIB_VERSION 3) which is important to include ride4dapps standard functionality(built-in functions) and the Postfix notation.

this line `{-# CONTENT_TYPE EXPRESSION #-}` represents the type of a contract which is

- **EXPRESSION** for smart accounts and smart assets.
- **DAPP** for ride4dApps.

The last line `{-# SCRIPT_TYPE ACCOUNT #-}` represents the script type, which is:

- ASSET for smart assets script.
- ACCOUNT for smart accounts and ride4dApps scripts.